# Puppeteer: No id for drop down selection

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to select a drop-down menu but there is no id to select. How can I make the selection and then the follow-up selection? In this case, I need to select All Transactions and then All tolls. Thank you for all the help.

```
//From first drop down

<div _ngcontent-mxw-c311="" ngclass.lt-md="filterItem" class="filterItem ng-star-inserted" style="margin-right: 10px;">
<ng-component _nghost-mxw-c298="" class="ng-star-inserted">
<div _ngcontent-mxw-c298="" fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="start start" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-start;">
<div _ngcontent-mxw-c298="" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutalign="space-between center" cdkoverlayorigin="" class="criteria-shape criteria-color criteria-size criteria-text criteria-hover" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: center space-between; align-items: center;">

//What is highlighted when I do an inspect

<span _ngcontent-mxw-c298="" style="color: #007aff; font-size: 14px;"> All Transactions </span>

<div _ngcontent-mxw-c298="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down chevron-color chevron-adjustment ng-star-inserted">
</div>
<!---->
</div>
<!---->
<!---->
</div>
</ng-component>
<!---->
</div>

//From the drop down I need to select

<div _ngcontent-mxw-c298="" fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="start start" class="ng-star-inserted" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-start;">
<div _ngcontent-mxw-c298="" class="transactionType-text criteria-hover">

//What is highlighted when I do an inspect

<span _ngcontent-mxw-c298="" class="parentItem">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;All Tolls</span>


</div>
</div>
```

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');

async function start(){ const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false}); const page = await browser.newPage(); await page.goto("https://www.hctra.org/Login");
await page.waitForSelector('#usernameTxtBox');

await page.type('#usernameTxtBox', 'xxxxxxx');
await page.type('#passwordTxtBox', 'xxxxxx');
await page.click('.btn.u-spacing--widthFill');
await page.waitForNavigation();
await page.goto("https://www.hctra.org/AccountActivity");
await page.$('[name="All Transactions"]');
await page.select ("All Transactions", "All Tolls");
await page.screenshot({path: "Reservation.png"});
await browser.close();
}

start()
```

Comment: Is there only one occurrence of the `transactionType-text` class being used?

Comment: You've to parse the template first, currently those elements are spans only.